# debian: how to install startup files using equivs-build?

Tags: debian, apt

I'm using `equivs-build` to package up some internal apps for distribution to our subsidiaries. Many require an equivalent script in **/etc/init.d** to kick off the app at boot.

Questions:

1. When I try to copy a file directly to **/etc/init.d** `apt-get` always appends ".dpkg-dist" to it. Why? It isn't appending anything to the my other files.
2. How would I go about setting up a link from **/etc/rc3.d** to the startup script in **/etc/init.d**?

EDIT: well it appears that #1 is due to the file (apparently) being a replacement for an existing version of the same. Except that there wasn't a file there before. So it appears that the install is copying in the file, then replacing it?

Comment: I strongly suggest you stop using `equivs-build` which isn't really meant to building useful packages.  Instead take a look at using [FPM](https://github.com/jordansissel/fpm/wiki) for building packages quickly.  My guess is that your package isn't setup properly for conffiles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this:

1. Copy the script control file to /tmp (via the `equivs-build` control file)
2. In the `postinst` file move it to */etc/init.d*
3. Run `/usr/sbin/update-rc.d <script file> defaults` to make the link to the appropriate */etc/rc.d* folders

Example:

```
#! /bin/sh

case "$1" in
    configure)
            if [ -f /tmp/runonce ]
            then
                    mv /tmp/script-monitor /etc/init.d
                    chmod oug+x /etc/init.d/script-monitor

                    /usr/sbin/update-rc.d script-monitor defaults
            fi
    ;;
esac
```